# Export all constants from another file

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I would like to create `index.js` file where all constants and default exports from another files will be exported. For example:

**userActions.js**:

```
export const login = (username, password) => { ... }
export const logout = () => { ... }
```

**User.js**:

```
export default class User { ... }
```

**Book.js**:

```
export default class Book { ... }
```

**index.js**

```
import { login, logout } from './userActions'
import Book from './Book'
import User from './User'

export { login, logout, Book, User }
```

And then, it will be possible this in any file:

```
import { login, Book, User } from './index.js'
```

Unfortunately, I often add new user actions and I don't want to change index.js every time. So I would like use this in **index.js**:

```
export * from './userActions'
```

Somewhere in another file (everything works)...

```
import * as allExports from './index.js'
console.log(allExports) // { login: ƒ, logout: ƒ, __esModule: true }
```

But if I add default exports to the named exports (**index.js**):

```
import Book from './Book'
import User from './User'
export * from './userActions'
export { Book, User }
```

There is only first default export (somewhere in another file):

```
import * as allExports from './index.js'
console.log(allExports) // { Book: f, __esModule: true }
// Expected output is: { Book: f, User: f, login: ƒ, logout: ƒ, __esModule: true }
```

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: What you have works just fine (just tested locally to be sure). However, you should use `export ... from` rather than `import` and then separate `export`. (`export { default as Book } from './Book';`)

Comment: Your code (with various missing `.js` [your bundler may not require them, native browser support does] and `;` added) working: https://embed.plnkr.co/E5DDTqyeEu54NMUmXIRy/ Using `export { default as...` instead: https://embed.plnkr.co/HgsofquuQ1hyeAgzCAuV/

Comment: Thanks for explanation! `export { default as Book}` is definitely better than `import Book` and `export { Book }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `export { default as name } from './resource'` to convert defaults to named exports:

```
export { default as Book } from './Book'
export { default as User } User from './User'
export * from './userActions'
```